# Efficient sending graph data structure over WAN

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, graph

I am looking for an efficient way of sending property graph over WAN. For the sake of latency and bandwidth I should make it as efficient as possible. One solution would be serializing the graph data structure and sending that in a chunk of smaller size over socket. This approach could be implemented in different ways. Probably the most obvious implementation would be sending graph in a serialized List of triple (vertex-edge-vertex) for all edges and serialized vertices for all disconnected vertices. However, it is clear that this solution is not efficient since vertices could be sent multiple times and can use lots of bandwidth.

I know graph data structure can be transferred using **adjacency list** and **adjacency matrix**, but I can not figure it out the way of serialization and sending that over WAN in these forms. I would be really grateful if somebody can help me with an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an adjacency matrix you still run into the issue of sending over unneeded data since you have to specify n^2 vertex connections (or lack thereof) so if you have a very sparsely connected graph you'll still have to send over at least n^2 bits of information.

One simple solution where you only use n^2 bits + 1 byte of information is to implicitly send the adjacency matrix.

Say you have `n` vertices. Number them arbitrarily from `1...n`. Then create an `n x n`adjacency matrix `A` where `A(i,j)==1` if an edge exists from vertex `i` to `j` and `0` if no such connection exists. As you can see, you will only need n^2 bits (not bytes!) to specify your adjacency matrix.

Then you serialize in this way:
At the beginning use 1 byte (32 bits), i.e an `int` to specify the size of your matrix (`n`). Then the next n^2 bits should be your adjacency matrix.

To deserialize, read the first byte to figure out the size of your adjacency matrix then read the next n^2 bits for the edge connections.

Note: even though I'm using the term matrix here to make it conceptually easy to think about, the data need not be explicitly structured in matrix fashion but can be stored in a linear fashion. Then to access row `i` column `j` you simply do `A(i*n+j)`.

Obviously this solution only send over the graph structure and not any actual data contained in the graph. However, I personally think this is still a good idea to do even if you need to send over actual data contained in the graph since once you have the graph structure, you can serialize the rest of the data however you want and reconstruct it on the other end.

Comment: What if vertices and edges hold some property? Your solution would be sending the serialized list of vertices separately with using some identifier, and sending corresponding adjacency matrix with putting each edge object ,which holds some properties, at the right cell?

Comment: No, the adjacency matrix would simply dictate the graph structure. If the vertices and edges contain some data, you're going to have to send this data separately (not much you can do there since this data must be sent over somehow).  However, the solution I'm proposing doesn't send any edges/vertices twice and uses a very compact adjacency matrix.

Comment: What about the Vertex and Edge objects? I have to create them at destination which means adding extra time for parsing properties and creating the whole graph according to adjacency matrix.